# Access Functions within jquery.iviewer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the iviewer jQuery plugin as a document viewer and I've got some customizations that require me to fire the events outside the default. It seems that what I am trying to do should be possible, but I can't be certain.

I have a button on my page with a div of iviewer_rotate_right.

```
<div class="iviewer_rotate_right">Rotate</div>
```

Then I use this listener to call on the iviewer.angle

```
$(".iviewer_rotate_right").click(function() {
  $(".viewer").iviewer.angle(90);
});
```

However, I get the following error in the console

```
$(".viewer").iviewer.angle is not a function
```

"viewer" is the class name of the div containing the image.

The plugin code is available here:

https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/blob/master/jquery.iviewer.js and the angle function begins on line 561.

Answer (score -1):

From the iviewer documentation, you call methods like this:

```
$('#viewer').iviewer('method', 'arg1', 'arg2')
```

Notice that this is calling the container #viewer by id not by class.

You can run the method on the class like you are trying to do in your example like this:

```
$(".iviewer_rotate_right").click(function() {
    $(".viewer").iviewer('angle', 90);
});
```

If you have multiple containers on your page with the class .viewer, all of them will rotate by 90 degrees.

The iviewer documentation can be found here: https://github.com/can3p/iviewer/wiki